# SBT with read-only base directory

Tags: scala, sbt, docker, sbt-revolver

I am experimenting with [SBT Revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) within a Docker container.  I am mounting the base directory as a Docker volume.  It works great, except for one problem: Docker does not map users, so I'm ending up with `project/project/` and `project/target/` directories that are not owned by the host user.

I was able to relocate the `target/` directory by adding this to the `build.sbt` in the base directory:

```
target := file("/data/target")
```

But I don't have a clue as to how to customize the location of the files created within the `project/` directory.

Is it possible in any way to have an SBT build where *all the build outputs* are created outside the base directory?

Comment: Not sure why you need to set `target` path... I have built an SBT container earlier and it works file with unmodified `build.sbt`, see here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/errordeveloper/sbt/

Comment: But I did find that the ownership of artefacts is a bit messy at the moment. There few compiler-in-docker things kicking around, one of which is docker/docker itself, I'd start there.

Comment: Nice dockerfile, and the jdk one too.  But the command you run `docker run -t -i -v `pwd`:/io errordeveloper/sbt:latest ';compile ;exit'` creates a target directory owned by root, no?  If you could move it outside the volume, you don't need to clean the host with sudo.

Comment: Yes, it is currently written as root. I am not exactly sure what you are suggesting, however, I would rather consider to implement a build tool plugin or just a script that pack artefacts into a new container image that can be uploaded to the registry. I have done the builder container which is all one needs for just building, next step is to assemble it into an app container image.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in any way to have an SBT build where all the build outputs are created outside the base directory?

I don't think we have a setting like that. You could add something like `project/build.sbt`:

```
target := file("/data/meta-target")
```

but it might actually force `project/project/target` and so on.

Comment: No, assigning `target` in `project/build.sbt` doesn't seem to work.  But +1 for asserting it's not possible, though I was really hoping it would be.

Comment: Well, technically, I'm sure it's possible, but you may need to edit SBT sources a bit...

It seems strange for a modern build system to not support a read-only source directory.